# Hyperledger Composer - Error starting the network

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm working with the Composer's "Deploying a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric" tutorial trying to setup my own network.

The only difference is that I integrated from the start a third organisation and when I'm calling the following command `./byfn.sh -m up -s couchdb -a` I'm not letting the chaincode install on to the peers. Because I'm going to install my own bna afterwards with composer. (I'm not really sure about this step, maybe I got this wrong.)

Moving forward with the tutorial, when I'm getting to the composer start network command, I'm receiving a strange error, that I could not find any reference anywhere.

```
composer network start -c PeerAdmin@testManager -n test-network -V 0.0.10 -o endorsementPolicyFile=/tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json -A andreim -C andreim/admin-pub.pem -A andreis -C andreis/admin-pub.pem -A andreii -C andreii/admin-pub.pem

Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Parameter must be a ProposalResponse Object
```

Any ideea would be really great. 
Regards.

**Update Information**

Fabric 1.2

Composer v0.19.12

The channel is created, with the peers joining and updating the anchor peers, successfully.

This is the Endorsement Policy:

```
{
    "identities": [
        {
            "role": {
                "name": "member",
                "mspId": "ManagerMSP"
            }
        },
        {
            "role": {
                "name": "member",
                "mspId": "SponsorMSP"
            }
        },
        {
            "role": {
                "name": "member",
                "mspId": "InsurerMSP"
            }
        }
    ],
    "policy": {
        "3-of": [
            {
                "signed-by": 0
            },
            {
                "signed-by": 1
            },
            {
                "signed-by": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the Connection Profile:

```
{
    "name": "test-network",
    "x-type": "hlfv1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
            "orderers": [
                "orderer.test.com"
            ],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.manager.test.com": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "ledgerQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },
                "peer1.manager.test.com": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "ledgerQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },
                "peer0.sponsor.test.com": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "ledgerQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },
                "peer1.sponsor.test.com": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "ledgerQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },
                "peer0.insurer.test.com": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "ledgerQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },
                "peer1.insurer.test.com": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "ledgerQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Manager": {
            "mspid": "ManagerMSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.manager.test.com",
                "peer1.manager.test.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.manager.test.com"
            ]
        },
        "Sponsor": {
            "mspid": "SponsorMSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.sponsor.test.com",
                "peer1.sponsor.test.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.sponsor.test.com"
            ]
        },
        "Insurer": {
            "mspid": "InsurerMSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.insurer.test.com",
                "peer1.insurer.test.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.insurer.test.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer.test.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:7050",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer.test.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "INSERT_ORDERER_CA_CERT"
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.manager.test.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
            "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:7053",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.manager.test.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "INSERT_MANAGER_CA_CERT"
            }
        },
        "peer1.manager.test.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:8051",
            "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:8053",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.manager.test.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "INSERT_MANAGER_CA_CERT"
            }
        },
        "peer0.sponsor.test.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:9051",
            "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:9053",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.sponsor.test.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "INSERT_SPONSOR_CA_CERT"
            }
        },
        "peer1.sponsor.test.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:10051",
            "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:10053",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.sponsor.test.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "INSERT_SPONSOR_CA_CERT"
            }
        },
        "peer0.insurer.test.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:11051",
            "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:11053",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.insurer.test.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "INSERT_INSURER_CA_CERT"
            }
        },
        "peer1.insurer.test.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:12051",
            "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:12053",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.insurer.test.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "INSERT_INSURER_CA_CERT"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.manager.test.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca-manager",
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        },
        "ca.sponsor.test.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:8054",
            "caName": "ca-sponsor",
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        },
        "ca.insurer.test.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:9054",
            "caName": "ca-insurer",
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Composer and Fabric do you have? (and what operating system)

Even though you say you are not letting the chaincode install - is the channel created and have the peers joined it? 

Can you share your endorsement policy and connection.json?

Comment: I've added more information. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you adding a `client` section to the connection.json as per step 3 of the Multi-Org tutorial?

Comment: Yes, I have a script that adds the client section, pem certs, etc.

Comment: You are trying to use composer 0.19 with fabric 1.2 they aren't compatible. You need to either use Fabric 1.1 or upgrade to composer 0.20

Comment: @david_k You are right. Once I upgraded to 0.20 the network started successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was trying to use Composer 0.19 with Fabric 1.2, an upgrade to Composer 0.20 was the solution.

Comment: I have a new issue now; When I tried starting the network with a bna made with 0.19, the network starts ok but I get an obvious error when trying to ping (0.19 not compatible with 0.20). So I created a new bna using composer 0.20 with the same contents and successfully installed it to the peers, but when I get to the network start command - my mac just hangs and brings the processor at 450%...

Answer (score 0):

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: invalid chaincode name 'student-business-network.bna'. Names can only consist of alphanumerics, '_', and '-'
Command failed

please any one provide the solution for this error

Comment: "student-business-network.bna" is the archive of the business model. The name of the business network should be without the ".bna" termination. Be careful what you are installing onto the peers.